# Disable Authentication in SAP Cloud Foundry App

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to disable login on my SAP Cloud Foundry app. Here is my **xs-app.json**

```
    {
  "authenticationMethod": "route",
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "/",
      "target": "/",
      "destination": "nodeBackend1",
      "csrfProtection": false,
      "authenticationType": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

And **manifest.yml**:

```
---
applications:

- name: appnode-demo
  host: appnode-demo-pxxxxtrial
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack.git
  memory: 128M
  services:
    - xsuaanode-demo
    - connectivity-demo-lite
    - destinationnode-demo-lite
```

I got this error message from the log file when accessing the page url (https://appnode-demo-pxxxxtrial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/)

> msg":"GET request to /nodeBackend1 completed with status 500 - Error
>   while retrieving destination nodeBackend1 from destination service.
>   HTTP status code: 400"}

If I changed the **authenticationType** on **xs-app.json** to **basic**, it is working fine (I need to enter my credential).

nodeBackend1 is a simple Nodejs http server app running on-premise (on my machine) connected to SAP Cloud Foundry with SAP Cloud Connector.

How to disable the authentication so I can access the page without entering my credential (make it public) ?

Comment: We have forwarded the question to some of our colleagues internally who should be able to help on answering this question.

Comment: Thanks Sander. Appreciated ! I was desperate to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any feedback on this please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no feedback yet. In the meantime, could you maybe provide a minimal non-working example?